# Set :defaults for route cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently setting a number of routes like so:

```
  post '/create', :to => 'reports#create', :defaults => {:format => 'json'}
  get '/all', :to => 'reports#index', :defaults => {:format => 'json'}
  delete '/:id', :to => 'reports#destroy', :defaults => {:format => 'json'}
  get '/:id', :to => 'reports#show', :defaults => {:format => 'json'}
  root :to => 'reports#index', :defaults => {:format => 'json'}
```

And I was wondering if there is any way to set `:defaults => {:format => 'json'}` for all of the routes in this cluster without having to write it out for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
defaults { :format => :json } do
  post '/create', :to => 'reports#create'
  get '/all', :to => 'reports#index'
  delete '/:id', :to => 'reports#destroy'
  get '/:id', :to => 'reports#show'
  root :to => 'reports#index'
end
```

Resources:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-defaults

Comment: That's perfect. Is that a new addition to Rails 4?

Comment: It's pretty nice :) its been in there since at least 2010-03-26 probably much earlier.